# Modificar datos de un archivo Json con Python

Tags: python, json

Tengo un archivo Json que quiero modificar con Python a una cierta estructura.
pero no consigo la forma de transformarlo a esa estructura.

La idea es añadir ese atributo `service_dbdata` y colocar los demás atributos como se muestra y separarlos por el `serviceID` cuando su valor sea diferente.

Mi archivo data.json:

```
[
    {
        "ingress": "Ingress",
        "evi": "1111",
        "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
        "sap_id": "88:2712",
        "serviceID": "754159888",
        "egress": "Egress"
    },
    {
        "ingress": "Ingress-S",
        "evi": "1111",
        "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
        "sap_id": "84:2713",
        "serviceID": "754159888",
        "egress": "Egress"
    },
    {
        "ingress": "Ingress-FW",
        "evi": "1111",
        "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
        "sap_id": "88:2715",
        "serviceID": "754159888",
        "egress": "Egress"
    },
    {
        "ingress": "Ingress-St",
        "evi": "2222",
        "L2DOMNAME": "VNeldis",
        "sap_id": "84:2716",
        "serviceID": "1299499565",
        "egress": "Egress"
    }
]
```

y quiero que tenga esta estructura:

```
  [
    {
        "serviceID": "754159888",
        "service_dbdata":[
            {
                "ingress": "Ingress",
                "evi": "1111",
                "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
                "sap_id": "88:2712",
                "egress": "Egress" 
            },
            {
                "ingress": "Ingress-S",
                "evi": "1111",
                "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
                "sap_id": "84:2713",
                "egress": "Egress"
            },
            {
                "ingress": "Ingress-FW",
                "evi": "1111",
                "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis",
                "sap_id": "88:2715",
                "egress": "Egress"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serviceID": "1299499565",
        "service_dbdata":[
            {
                "ingress": "Ingress-St",
                "evi": "2222",
                "L2DOMNAME": "Neldis_t2",
                "sap_id": "84:2716",
                "egress": "Egress"
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

los separo por el serviceID.
Utilizo el modulo json.

```
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
  d= json.loads(f.read())
```

Lo complicado que veo es como mover esos atributos e insertarlos para que forme esa estructura.

Comment: ¿Qué probaste hasta ahora? Copia el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primero, separar diccionarios según su id

Puedes tener un diccionario cuyas claves sean los valores de *id* que vayas encontrando, y cuyos valores sean listas que contendrán los diccionarios que tenían ese *id*.

Esto es sencillo de implementar con un `defaultdict` de listas:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for dic in d:
  id = dic.pop("serviceID")
  result[id].append(dic)
```

El `dic.pop()` tiene un doble cometido, por un lado te retorna el "serviceID" del diccionario que en ese momento se esté procesando, y además te elimina esa clave del diccionario (pues he visto que en tu resultado final ya no quieres que la tengan). Ten en cuenta que este bucle modifica tu diccionario `d` al eliminarle el "serviceID" de cada sub-diccionario. Si deseas conservar `d` con su valor original tendrías que hacer antes un *deepcopy*.

Una vez termina el bucle anterior, la variable `result` contiene:

```
{'1299499565': [
  {'L2DOMNAME': 'VNeldis',
    'egress': 'Egress',
    'evi': '2222',
    'ingress': 'Ingress-St',
    'sap_id': '84:2716'}],
'754159888': [
  {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
    'egress': 'Egress',
    'evi': '1111',
    'ingress': 'Ingress',
    'sap_id': '88:2712'},
  {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
    'egress': 'Egress',
    'evi': '1111',
    'ingress': 'Ingress-S',
    'sap_id': '84:2713'},
  {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
    'egress': 'Egress',
    'evi': '1111',
    'ingress': 'Ingress-FW',
    'sap_id': '88:2715'}]}
```

### Segundo, convertir ese resultado a tu formato

Lo que tenemos es un diccionario en el que las claves son los id, y los valores son listas. Tú lo que quieres es una lista de diccionarios. Cada diccionario debe tener una clave "serviceID" con el id, y otra clave "service_dbdata" con la lista.

Es sencillo convertir nuestro `result` al formato que tú quieres con una comprensión de listas:

```
final = [ {"serviceID": k, "service_dbdata":v} for k,v in result.items()]
```

En `final` queda lo siguiente:

```
[{'serviceID': '754159888',
  'service_dbdata': [
      {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
        'egress': 'Egress',
        'evi': '1111',
        'ingress': 'Ingress',
        'sap_id': '88:2712'},
      {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
        'egress': 'Egress',
        'evi': '1111',
        'ingress': 'Ingress-S',
        'sap_id': '84:2713'},
      {'L2DOMNAME': 'Neldis',
        'egress': 'Egress',
        'evi': '1111',
        'ingress': 'Ingress-FW',
        'sap_id': '88:2715'}]
  },
  {'serviceID': '1299499565',
   'service_dbdata': [
      {'L2DOMNAME': 'VNeldis',
        'egress': 'Egress',
        'evi': '2222',
        'ingress': 'Ingress-St',
        'sap_id': '84:2716'}]
   }
 ]
```